Error connecting S3 Minio Object Store to Artifactory
What could be the problem? Maybe I need to add some more parameters to binarystore.xml. I also don't understand why it tries to connect to port 443 if I specified 9000.
binarystore.xml file:
<config version="2">
        <chain template="s3-storage-v3"/>
        <provider id="s3-storage-v3" type="s3-storage-v3">
                <endpoint>http://s3_minio_ip:9000</endpoint>
                <identity>username</identity>
                <credential>password</credential>
                <path></path>
                <bucketName>test</bucketName>
        </provider>
</config>

Error encountered when starting Artifactory:
2024-10-21T09:28:22.624Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [f030324f462f1e16] [ifactoryApplicationContext:288] [art-init            ] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'blobInfoServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-addons-common-7.59.13.jar!/org/artifactory/addon/common/blobinfo/BlobInfoServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'replicatorServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-addons-common-7.59.13.jar!/org/artifactory/addon/common/replicator/ReplicatorServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artifactDistributionStatusWriterServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'taskService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'addonsManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addonsManagerImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEntitlementService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JFConnectServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAccessService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCentralConfigService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centralConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBuildService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'buildServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUploadService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTrafficService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'trafficServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepositoryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryStore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artifactoryBinaryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryInternalService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request:Connect to 172.17.14.223:443 [/172.17.14.223] failed: Connection refused

2024-10-21T09:28:22.636Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [f030324f462f1e16] [ctoryContextConfigListener:126] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: Connection refused
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
  at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:267)
  at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:122)


From the error, it indicates that the AWS SDK is trying to connect using port 443; however, in the configuration, we have specified port 9000. By default, Artifactory uses HTTPS (port 443), which the useHttp parameter in the binarystore.xml can control.
Try updating the binarystore.xml as shown below and test:
<config version="2">
    <chain template="s3-storage-v3"/>
    <provider id="s3-storage-v3" type="s3-storage-v3">
        <endpoint>http://s3_minio_ip</endpoint>
        <useHttp>true</useHttp>
        <port>9000</port>
        <identity>username</identity>
        <credential>password</credential>
        <path>filestore</path>
        <enablePathStyleAccess>true</enablePathStyleAccess>
        <bucketName>test</bucketName>
    </provider>
</config>

For more information on each parameter, you can refer to the JFrog wiki: Amazon S3 Template Parameters.
Also, confirm the proxy variables for the Artifactory/server. If the connection to S3(s3_minio) does not require a proxy, then the endpoint should be included in the no_proxy variable.
